# Vault backend storage, how many buckets need for at least one cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, bucket, hashicorp-vault

i am studying an arquitecture for Vault, on the website i found recomendations for the storage backend using Consul, but i am thinking using buckets on Google Cloud Storage to store secrets. They say using Consul is necessery at least 7 instances of Consul on a Vault cluster 5 of them is only to vault(i know Consul is more than a storage service), but i dont know how it works using buckets, can i say the number of instances is the same amount of buckets to have a decent disponibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one Cloud Storage bucket. In fact, you can only have one bucket:

```
storage "gcs" {
  bucket = "my-storage-bucket"
}
```

You have to make the bucket first, which you can do via the web ui or using the gsutil cli:

```
gsutil mb gs://mycompany-vault-data
```

For more information, see the [Vault Cloud Storage backend documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/google-cloud-storage/)